# Multidimensional array without repeating

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

I have two MySQL tables, one is called "version" and the other is called "lines" inside one DB called "project".

The "version" table consist of:

```
id (PRIMARY / AI) = int
version           = string
```

Rows:

```
# | version
------------
0 | 100
1 | 200
3 | 400
```

The "lines" table consist of:

```
id (PRIMARY / AI) = int
lines             = string
version_id        = string (ID from table version)
```

Rows:

```
# | line     | version_id
--------------------------
0 | line #1  | 0
1 | line #2  | 0
2 | line #3  | 1
3 | line #4  | 0
4 | line #5  | 1
```

How can I create multidimensional array to output an example JSON (pseudo)

```
"full" =>
    "version" => "100"
        "id"    => "0", (version id table)
        "line"  =>
            "row_0" => "line #1", (from lines table)
            "row_1" => "line #2",
            "row_2" => "line #4",
    "version" => "200"
        "id" => "1",
        "line" =>
            "row_0" => "line #3",
            "row_1" => "line #5",
    "version" => "300"
        "id" => "3",
        "line" => "EMPTY" (no lines for this version)
]
```

I rewrote the code a couple of times but I can't make it work. Either I stuck or I finish in infinite loop of errors. This is what I got for now:

```
function returnJson() {
    $db = DB::query("SELECT * FROM version");

    foreach ($db as $row) {
        $i++;
        $lines = DB::Query("SELECT * FROM lines WHERE version_id=%i", $row['id']);

        // approach to nested array?
    }
}
```

I'm using MeekroDB so any approach to MySQL is offset. You can write an example in PDO if you are more familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the array you want would look like this in php:

```
"full" =>
    "100" => array (
        "versionId"    => "0", (version id table)
        "line"  =>
            "row_0" => "line #1", (
            "row_1" => "line #2",
            "row_2" => "line #4"
    )
    , "200" => array (
        "versionId" => "1",
        "line" => array (
            "row_0" => "line #3",
            "row_1" => "line #5" )
    )
    , "300" => array (
        "versionId" => "3",
        "line" => array()
    )
]
```

Use a JOIN

```
SELECT v.id AS versionId, v.version l.id as linesId, l.lines
FROM version v
INNER JOIN lines l ON v.id = l.version_id
```

And then a loop with some if statement to build the array

```
$versions = array();

foreach($db as $row) {
  if (!isset($versions[$db["version"]]))
    $versions[$db["version"]] = array (
      "versionId" =>  $db["versionId"],
      "line" => array()
    );
  if (!empty($db["lines"]))
    $versions[$db["version"]][lines"][] = $db["lines"];
}
```

Comment: That is much tidier then my version of the code. I'll update you tomorrow with a result of your version as it's already 4AM. Thank you for contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the accepted answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567219/mysqli-append-more-deeper-results/34568119?noredirect=1#comment56882812_34568119) which also deals with nested JSON data.

Also you may want to reduce your SQL to below and just use one loop instead of 2 nested loops as in the SO post above.

```
SELECT *
  FROM version
 INNER 
  JOIN lines
    ON version.id = lines.version_id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was extremely helpful, also, @Terminus wrote a code based on JOIN. I already coded my own but his seems alot tidier.